# s3 vs dynamoDB for gps data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have the following situation that I try to find the best solution for. 
A device writes its GPS coordinates every second to a csv file and uploads the file every x minutes to s3 before starting a new csv.

Later I want to be able to get the GPS data for a specific time period e.g 2016-11-11 8am  until 2016-11-11 2pm

Here are two solutions that I am currently considering:

1. Use a lambda function to automatically save the csv data to a dynamoDB record
2. Only save the metadata (csv gps timestamp-start, timestamp-end, s3Filename) in dynamoDB and then request the files directly from s3.

However both solutions seem to have a major drawback:

1. The gps data uses about 40 bytes per record (second). So if I use 10min chunks this will result in a 24 kB file. dynamoDB charges write capacities by item size (1 write capacity unit = 1 kB). So this would require 24 units for a single write. Reads (4kB/unit) are even worse since a user may request timeframes greater than 10 min. So for a request covering e.g. 6 hours (=864kB) it would require a read capacity of 216. This will just be too expensive considering multiple users.
2. When I read directly from S3 I face the browser limiting the number of concurrent requests. The 6 hour timespan for instance would cover 36 files. This might still be acceptable, considering a connection limit of 6. But a request for 24 hours (=144 files) would just take too long.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

best regards, Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using DynamoDB altogether if the S3 keys contain the date in a reasonable format (e.g. ISO: `deviceid_2016-11-27T160732`). This allows you to find the correct files by listing the object keys: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html.

(If you can not control the naming, you could use a Lambda function to rename the files.)

Number of requests is an issue, but you could try to put a CloudFront distribution in front of it and utilize HTTP/2, which allows the browser to request multiple files over the same connection.

Comment: These are good ideas. Strategically placed `/` characters in the key might lend themselves better to the S3 API's prefix+delimiter object listing logic.  And, of course there's gzip, which could be done on the client before uploading, or with Lambda+S3 events on the backend when files come in (saves storage space), or on-the-fly with CloudFront (zero effort but probably not `-9`-level compression).  Sane user-agents will automatically undo the compression on download if the `Content-Encoding` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [AWS Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/)? Your data will be periodically shovelled into Redshift which is like Postgres. You just pump a JSON formatted or a | delimited record into an AWS Firehose end-point and the rest is magic by the little AWS elves.